# Error on dashboard refresh: this report cannot be used as the source for this compenent

Tags: dashboard

[image]

> Error: This report cannot be used as the source for this component. If it is a summary or matrix report, add one or more groupings in the report. If it is a tabular report with a row limit, specify the Dashboard Settings in the report.

I am getting this error while refreshing a dashboard.

Comment: The answer is in the error message

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce has a [help](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=What-are-common-Dashboard-Component-Errors&language=en_US) article on common dashboard component errors that describes the resolution for this issue: 
Resolution:   If it is a summary or matrix report, you need to add one or more groupings in the report.

> If the source report of the dashboard's component is in Summary
>   format, please make sure that the running user of the dashboard has at
>   least a read only access to the field that is used to summarize or
>   group the report.
>
> If the report is in a tabular format, please make sure that you
>   selected a row limit and specified the dashboard settings. You need to
>   customize the Report and then click on the "Dashboard Settings" button
>   that will appear on the "save" bar below the name of the report. 
>   Specify the Value and then click OK and Save.
>
> For further information about what Matrix or summary reports are,
>   please review the article [Choose a Report Format](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_changing_format.htm&language=en_US)

If this report was working previously on the dashboard and stopped working, more than likely someone went in and modified the report without realizing it would break the dashboard.

Comment: Interestingly, this issue can also happen if one deploys a dashboard with a particular running user that doesn't have the FLS, then changes the running user in the meta-data to a new running user that does have the FLS and then deploy to the org. I had to delete the dashboard and re-deploy again with the latest running user and this then worked.